# Migrated database from sqlserver to mysql seems to have error in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-2

I have completed migrating database from sqlserver to mysql but it seems to have problems in rails. When i fetch record in rails console for eg:

```
 <AuthAdmin:0xb6e506f8 @attributes={"Status"=>"1", "LastUpdateSeqNo"=>nil, "CreationDate"=>"2005-08-03 22:53:57", "AuthAdminID"=>"8987", "PropertyID"=>nil, "Password"=>"trustbss", "LastUpdate"=>"2012-07-12 05:15:02", "UserType"=>"0", "LoginName"=>"dev"}
```

Now attributes such as CreationDate and AuthAdminID suppose to be date and integer are displaying as string.But when I do

```
  AuthAdmin.find(:first).AuthAdminID.class output is Fixnum
```

You can check record given above,it shows string. Now when i do arithmatic operation in my views caught issue string can't be coerced into Fixnum.Explicitly changing everything to their own TYPE is a very bad idea.

Hope that explain my problem.
Look like no one come across this problem.

Comment: The first object notation is representing the value as a string but when accessing the property you seem to get the right value with the right type... so this seems to be working pretty well, right ?

Comment: Yes, But incase you are sending data to view file and performing some operation it is recieved as a string.